# Applying different shifts to a specific column of grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe like

```
In [1]: features

Out[1]:
                             ndvi_ne ndvi_sw   precipitation_amt_mm  reanalysis_air_temp_k
city    year    weekofyear
sj      1990    18           0.122600 0.10372  12.42                 297.572857
                19           0.145601 0.16920  10.02                 295.514578
                20           0.110496 0.00366  4.15                  299.174907
...     ...     ...          ...      ...      ...                   ...
iq      2010    20           0.197400 0.05218  11.45                 295.508559
                21           0.173843 0.05270  17.02                 296.062779
                22           0.051905 0.74994  10.15                 297.073854
```

I want groupby the dataframe by index 'city' and shift by lets say 2 the **reanalysis_air_temp_k** column of the **'sj' group**. And shift by lets say 1 the same column of the **'iq' group**.

But here

```
features.groupby('city')['precipitation_amt_mm'].shift(1)
```

shifts ['precipitation_amt_mm'] column of both 'sj' and 'iq' groups by 1

It seems that groupby method doesn't have funtionality to apply different shifts to the same column of different groups.

Any idea or method is appreciated on how to do the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a dictionary for the amount to shift for each group (city), you can use a for loop and shift by that amount.

```
shifts = {"sj": 2, "iq": 1}

for grp, vals in features.reset_index(drop=False).set_index("city").groupby("city"):
    print(vals["precipitation_amt_mm"].shift(shifts[grp]))
```

Assuming you then want to return this to the dataframe:

```
import itertools

# chain the list of lists to one list
features["precipitation_amt_mm"] = list(itertools.chain(
    # create a list for each groupby group (in "city")
    # shifting the "precipitation_amt_mm" col using dictionary
    *[list(vals["precipitation_amt_mm"].shift(shifts[grp]).values) \
      # for each group in the dataframe, reseting the multi-index to just "city" temporarily
      for grp, vals in features.reset_index(drop=False).set_index("city").groupby("city")]))

#                       ndvi_ne ndvi_sw  precipitation_amt_mm  reanalysis_air_temp_k
#city year weekofyear                                                               
#sj   1990 18          0.122600 0.10372                   NaN             297.572857
#          19          0.145601 0.16920                 11.45             295.514578
#          20          0.110496 0.00366                 17.02             299.174907
#iq   2010 20          0.197400 0.05218                   NaN             295.508559
#          21          0.173843 0.05270                   NaN             296.062779
#          22          0.051905 0.74994                 12.42             297.073854
```

Comment: yes exactly I want the result that you have shown but the code you have provided yield different result.

Comment: I think groupby object's grp names swaps the order of group. i.e. grp = ['iq', 'sj'], where it  should be grp = ['sj', 'iq']

Comment: Yes, that is correct, because the groupby sorts the values.  You can pass an argument in the groupby to not sort the values.  In the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) you can see that the default for sort is True, you can use `sort=False` to prevent that.